# Camera Timestamp Glitching error

Tags: permissions, 22.04, camera

Recently my camera on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (64 bit) started to have problems. The camera would repeat frames and ultimately not show any newer frames than the snippet at the beginning.

The program I was using to capture images was Cheese, when running in the command line it would output the message

> (cheese:4398): cheese-WARNING **: 13:53:33.993: A lot of buffers are being dropped.: ../libs/gst/base/gstbasesink.c(3143):   gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstViewfinderBin:vf-bin/ClutterGstVideoSink:cluttergstvideosink0:
> There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.

This behavior changes however, if I run Cheese with sudo instead, its outputting this:

```
(cheese:4458): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:54:56.298: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.546: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.546: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.546: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.548: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.548: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.548: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.548: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.549: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.550: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.551: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.551: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.553: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.553: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.553: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.554: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:54:56.554: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.555: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.557: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.557: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.557: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.562: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
(cheese:4458): dconf-WARNING **: 13:54:56.562: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
```

The strange thing is that running it with sudo allowed the camera to begin functioning again.
Does anyone know how to fix it so that I do not need to use sudo to use my camera?

Comment: Does the `id` command show your user is in the `video` group? If not, add yourself with: ```
sudo adduser $USER video
``` Then, logoff and login again. Groups are set up at `login` time.

Comment: try lower the resolution in preferences menu

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve the issue as I will need full resolution, I just want to know how I can do 1080p without having to run programs as superuser